# T-SQL заполнение таблиц связанных через транзитную

Tags: sql, хранимые-процедуры

```
CREATE TABLE books (
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
CONSTRAINT PK_books_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
title NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
comment NVARCHAR(100),
pages INT,
product_year INT,
publisher_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
CONSTRAINT FK_books_publisher_id FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id)
REFERENCES publishers(id),
)

CREATE TABLE genres(
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
CONSTRAINT PK_genres_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
title NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE genres_books (
genre_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
book_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_genre_id FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)
REFERENCES genres(id),
CONSTRAINT FK_book_id FOREIGN KEY (book_id)
REFERENCES books(id),
)
```

Мне нужно добавить книгу в таблицу books. Книга может иметь несколько tags поэтому создается промежуточная таблица tags_books дабы избежать дублирование и не усложнять переборку книг

На момент занесения записи в tags_books нужно уже знать id книги, который представляет собой тип UNIQUEIDENTIFIER и устанавливается по умолчанию с помощью NEWSEQUENTIALID().

Но как его узнать, если INSERT INTO не содержит информации о том, какой id будет установлен автоматически.

Видел примеры, где используется

```
DECLARE @NewPersonId INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

однако тип моего id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER и такое не работает.

Попытка сделать INSERT и тут же SELECT выглядит неудачно, так как проблема с синхронизациями запросов, а также кроме id в таблице books нет больше уникальных столбцов.

Помогите выйти из этой ситуации. Думаю случай тривиальный, но я не могу правильно задать вопрос в гугле.

**↓ Мое решение ↓**

---

```
USE BookStore
GO

CREATE TABLE authors (
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_authors_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT DF_authors_id DEFAULT NEWGUID() FOR id,
full_name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
adress NVARCHAR(100),
phone_number NVARCHAR(50),
)

CREATE TABLE tags (
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_tags_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT DF_tags_id DEFAULT NEWID() FOR id,
title NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT UK_tags_title UNIQUE (title)
)

CREATE TABLE genres (
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_genres_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT DF_genres_id DEFAULT NEWID() FOR id,
title NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT UK_genres_title UNIQUE (title)
)    

CREATE TABLE publishers (
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_publishers_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT DF_publishers_id DEFAULT NEWID() FOR id,
full_name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
adress NVARCHAR(100),
phone_number NVARCHAR(50),
)

CREATE TABLE books (
id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_books_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT DF_books_id DEFAULT NEWID() FOR id,
title NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
comment NVARCHAR(100),
pages INT,
product_year INT,
publisher_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
CONSTRAINT FK_books_publisher_id FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id)
REFERENCES publishers(id),
)
    
CREATE TABLE authors_books (
author_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
book_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_authors_books_author_id FOREIGN KEY (author_id)
REFERENCES authors(id),
CONSTRAINT FK_authors_books_book_id FOREIGN KEY (book_id)
REFERENCES books(id),
CONSTRAINT PK_authors_books PRIMARY KEY (author_id, book_id)
--CONSTRAINT UQ_authors_books UNIQUE (author_id, book_id),
)

CREATE TABLE tags_books (
tag_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
book_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_tags_books_tag_id FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)
REFERENCES tags(id),
CONSTRAINT FK_tags_books_book_id FOREIGN KEY (book_id)
REFERENCES books(id),
CONSTRAINT PK_tags_books PRIMARY KEY (tag_id, book_id)
--CONSTRAINT UQ_tags_books UNIQUE (tag_id, book_id),
)

CREATE TABLE genres_books (
genre_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
book_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_genre_id FOREIGN KEY (genre_id)
REFERENCES genres(id),
CONSTRAINT FK_book_id FOREIGN KEY (book_id)
REFERENCES books(id),
CONSTRAINT PK_genres_books PRIMARY KEY (genre_id, book_id)
--CONSTRAINT UQ_genres_books UNIQUE (genre_id, book_id),
)
    
--"PK_" - PRIMARY KEY

--"FK_" - FOREIGN KEY

--"CK_" - CHECK

--"UQ_" - UNIQUE

--"DF_" - DEFAULT

USE BookStore
GO
    
INSERT INTO authors(full_name, adress, phone_number)
VALUES
 (N'Taras Grygorovych Shevchenko', N'Ukraine, Kyiv', NULL),
 (N'Vsevolod Nestayko', N'Ukraine, Odessa', NULL),
 (N'Ivan Nechuy-Levytskyi', N'Ukraine, Kharkiv', NULL),
 (N'Ivan Kotlyarevskyi', N'Ukraine, Kharkiv', NULL),
 (N'Lesya Ukrainka', N'Ukraine', NULL),
 (N'Panas Mirnyi', N'Ukraine, Simpheropol', NULL),
 (N'Vasyl Barka', N'Ukraine', NULL),
 (N'Mykhailo Kotsyubynskyi', N'Ukraine, Lviv', NULL);

INSERT INTO publishers(full_name, adress, phone_number)
VALUES (N'Osvita', N'Kyiv', N'0001'),
 (N'Veselka', N'Kyiv', N'0002'),
 (N'Kamenyar', N'Lviv', N'0003'),
 (N'Karpaty', N'Uzhgorod', N'0004'),
 (N'Mayak', N'Odessa', N'0005'),
 (N'Molod', N'Kharkiv', N'0006'),
 (N'Naukova Dumka', N'Kyiv', N'0007'),
 (N'Tavriya', N'Simpheropol', N'0008');

INSERT INTO genres (title)
VALUES (N'Hystical'), (N'Drama'), (N'Documentary'), (N'Fantasy'),
    (N'Fiction'), (N'Detective'), (N'Love novel'), (N'Erotica'),
    (N'Thriller'), (N'Horror'), (N'Adventures'), (N'Prose'), (N'Poetry');

INSERT INTO tags (title)
VALUES (N'murder'), (N'scuffle'), (N'space'), (N'survival'),
    (N'big money'), (N'revenge'), (N'surprise end'), (N'with pictures'),
    (N'violence'), (N'humor'), (N'feelings'), (N'erotica'), (N'facts');
GO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertBook
    @BookTitle nvarchar(50),
    @Comment nvarchar(100),
    @Pages INT,  
    @ProductYear INT,
    @PublisherName nvarchar(50),
    @AuthorName nvarchar(MAX),
    @GenreName nvarchar(MAX),
    @TagName nvarchar(MAX)  
AS  
    --- Get PublisherGUID
    DECLARE @publisherID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;  
    SELECT TOP 1 @publisherID=id
    FROM publishers
    WHERE @PublisherName = full_name;
        
    --- Insert Book 
    DECLARE @bookID TABLE (id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);    
    INSERT INTO books (title, comment, pages, product_year, publisher_id)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @bookID
    VALUES (@BookTitle, @Comment, @Pages, @ProductYear, @publisherID);
        
    --- Get TagsGUIDs begin                 
    INSERT INTO tags_books (tag_id, book_id)
    SELECT _tag.id, _book.id
    FROM (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@TagName,';')) AS tagsNames
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 id
        FROM tags
        WHERE title = tagsNames.VALUE   
    ) _tag
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 id
        FROM @bookID AS bookIds
    ) _book
    
    --- Get AuthorsGUIDs begin
    INSERT INTO authors_books (author_id, book_id)
    SELECT _author.id, _book.id
    FROM (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@AuthorName,';')) AS authorsNames
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 id
        FROM authors
        WHERE full_name = authorsNames.VALUE    
    ) _author
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 id
        FROM @bookID AS bookIds
    ) _book
        
    --- Get GenresGUIDs begin
    INSERT INTO genres_books (genre_id, book_id)
    SELECT _genre.id, _book.id
    FROM (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT(@GenreName,';')) AS genresNames
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 id
        FROM genres
        WHERE title = genresNames.VALUE 
    ) _genre
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 id
        FROM @bookID AS bookIds
    ) _book
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXEC InsertBook @BookTitle = N'Kotygoroshko', @Comment = N'This is Comment1', @Pages = 321, @ProductYear = 1956, @PublisherName = N'Mayak', 
@AuthorName = N'Panas Mirnyi;Vsevolod Nestayko', @GenreName = N'Drama;Prose', @TagName = N'facts;humor'
GO

EXEC InsertBook @BookTitle = N'Space advanture', @Comment = N'This is Comment2', @Pages = 124, @ProductYear = 2001, @PublisherName = N'Naukova Dumka', 
@AuthorName = N'Panas Mirnyi;Lesya Ukrainka', @GenreName = N'Documentary;Fiction;Adventures', @TagName = N'facts;big money'
GO

EXEC InsertBook @BookTitle = N'Lovely novell', @Comment = N'This is Comment3', @Pages = 564, @ProductYear = 1968, @PublisherName = N'Veselka', 
@AuthorName = N'Ivan Nechuy-Levytskyi;Vasyl Barka', @GenreName = N'Drama;Love novel;Prose', @TagName = N'feelings;humor;revenge'
GO

EXEC InsertBook @BookTitle = N'Murder in village', @Comment = N'This is Comment4', @Pages = 445, @ProductYear = 1998, @PublisherName = N'Molod', 
@AuthorName = N'Mykhailo Kotsyubynskyi;Vasyl Barka', @GenreName = N'Adventures;Detective', @TagName = N'murder;humor;surprise end'
GO

EXEC InsertBook @BookTitle = N'The Sunshine world', @Comment = N'This is Comment5', @Pages = 247, @ProductYear = 2001, @PublisherName = N'Mayak', 
@AuthorName = N'Taras Grygorovych Shevchenko;Panas Mirnyi', @GenreName = N'Drama;feelings;Fantasy', @TagName = N'space;erotica'
GO
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---For Testing
SELECT * 
FROM books
JOIN publishers ON books.publisher_id = publishers.id
WHERE books.id IN (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM books)

SELECT * 
FROM genres_books
LEFT JOIN genres ON genres.id = genres_books.genre_id
WHERE genres_books.book_id IN (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM books)

SELECT * 
FROM tags_books
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tags_books.tag_id
WHERE tags_books.book_id IN (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM books)

SELECT * 
FROM authors_books
LEFT JOIN authors ON authors.id = authors_books.author_id
WHERE authors_books.book_id IN (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM books)
```

**↑ Может оно в живую и не проканает, но есть от чего отталкиваться. ↑**

Comment: используйте выражение OUTPUT

Comment: Как вариант, генерировать guid на клиенте.

Comment: declare @t table(id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) ;   insert books(... ) ...OUTPUT inserted.id into @t (id) VALUES (...); INSERT into genres_book (genre_id, book_id) select 1 as genre_id, id from @t